# Magento events Vagrant to production not firing

Tags: linux, magento, nginx, vagrant, percona

I have been stumped on this one for quite awhile. My magento event fires in my vagrant box but does not fire in my production (QA) environment.  My config file is as follows.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
   <modules>
        <Company_collectBillToCode>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Company_collectBillToCode>
   </modules>
   <global>
        <models>
            <company_collectbilltocode>
                <class>Company_collectBillToCode_Model</class>
            </company_collectbilltocode>
        </models>
        <events>
            <controller_action_predispatch_checkout_onepage_saveBilling>
                <observers>
                    <!--observer is location of the phtml file to be executed-->
                    <company_collectbilltocode>
                        <class>company_collectbilltocode/observer</class>
                        <method>capturebillto</method>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                    </company_collectbilltocode>
                </observers>
            </controller_action_predispatch_checkout_onepage_saveBilling>
        </events>
   </global>
</config>
```

The event fires as normal in a Vagrant instance, but does not fire in my production(QA) instance. This is an exact copy from git into the production(QA) environment.  I am leaning on this being a permissions issue. I have set ownership to www-data with 775 permissions, with no success.

My Observer.php:

```
<?php
//fires after billing info is saved
class Company_collectBillToCode_Model_Observer{
    public function captureBillTo(Varien_Event_Observer $observer){
        $customerGroupId=Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId();
        $customerGroupName=Mage::getModel('customer/group')->load($customerGroupId)->getCustomerGroupCode();

        //confirm this is an international order, and then collect the information as needed
        if($customerGroupName=='Internal_International'){
            $billingInfo=Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->getParams()['billing'];
            Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setBillToCode($billingInfo['bill-to']);
        }
    }
}
?>
```

And finally the module:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Company_collectBillToCode>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Company_collectBillToCode>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Comment: Did You clear cache after deploying it to production? Are You absolutely sure that event doesn't fire? make simple check with `Mage::log('observer test');` in 1st line of captureBillTo method. Than check your system.log

Comment: I have cleared the cache, and recompiled, and reindexed.  I put in a basic Mage::log('the event fired', null, 'eventLog.log') and the log was not created.